# Export dc.js Table with TableExport.js to csv and xls doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-csv, dc.js

I have created a **table** with [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) and I want to **export** its content to many extensions **csv** and **xls** for instance.

I found a plugin called [TableExport.js](https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/), but I did not get a nice result. And this is what I have in my js and html files :

**Js file**

```
datatable = $('#table');

dc.dataTable('.table')

        .dimension(Freq)

        .group(function(d) { 
            return ""; 
                            })
        .size(100)

        .columns([


            {
                label: 'xxxxx', 
                format: function (d) {

 return d.yyyy; }
},
            {
                label: 'xxxxx', 
                format: function (d) {

 return d.yyyy; }
},
            {
                label: 'xxxxx', 
                format: function (d) {

 return d.yyyy; }
},
            {
                label: 'xxxxx', 
                format: function (d) {

 return d.yyyy; }
}

])


        .sortBy(function (d) {
            return d.zzzz;
        })

        .order(d3.descending)

        .renderlet(function (table) {
            table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
        });
```

Here the part of the plugin `TableExport.js` :

```
$("table").tableExport({
    headings: true,                     // (Boolean), display table headings (th/td elements) in the <thead>
    footers: true,                      // (Boolean), display table footers (th/td elements) in the <tfoot>
    formats: ["xls", "csv", "txt", "xlsx"],     // (String[]), filetype(s) for the export
    fileName: "id",                     // (id, String), filename for the downloaded file
    bootstrap: true,                    // (Boolean), style buttons using bootstrap
    position: "top",                 // (top, bottom), position of the caption element relative to table
    ignoreRows: null,                   // (Number, Number[]), row indices to exclude from the exported file
    ignoreCols: null,                   // (Number, Number[]), column indices to exclude from the exported file
    ignoreCSS: ".tableexport-ignore"    // (selector, selector[]), selector(s) to exclude from the exported file
});
```

**Html file**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/xlsx.core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/blob.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/FileSaver.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/tableexport.js'></script>

<table class="table table-hover"></table>
```

**The result :**

I have these buttons like this :

[image]

But when I click on any button I get an empty file, like if my dynamic columns created by dc.js are not considered ...

Please any solution for that ?

Comment: dc.js has a weird table format due to the "groups" it creates, with headings inside the table. I suspect this is the culprit. But just to be sure - you know that your selectors are a bit strange for both dc.dataTable and tableExport, right? The first is looking for something with `class` table, and the second will pick up *any* table.

Comment: Yes I see, do you have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: Again, I doubt this is the problem. But usually one will give an `id` attribute to the table, and select with `#` selector. I don't know this TableExport.js but if you create a fiddle (or equivalent) I'd be happy to take a look at why it's not working. Probably because dc.js creates a ton of `<tbody>`s when most libraries expect at most 1.